# Extend existing component class in JIRA

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jira

I'm writing plugin for Jira 6.3.
I want to extend Jira's interface `com.atlassian.jira.bc.issue.attachment.AttachmentService`:

```
public interface MyAttachmentService extend AttachmentService {
    ...
}
```

then I implemented my interface:

```
public class MyDefaultAttachmentService extends DefaultAttachmentService implements MyAttachmentService {
    ...
}
```

I defined my class as a component in atlassian-plugin.xml:

```
<component key="myAttachmentService" name="MyAttachmentService" class="com.my.plugin.issue.attachment.MyDefaultAttachmentService">
    <interface>com.my.plugin.issue.attachment.MyAttachmentService</interface>
</component>
```

There is how I use my plugin's class (dependency injection):

```
public class DoSomethingWithAttachmentAction extends AbstractIssueSelectAction 
{
    private final MyAttachmentService myAttachmentService ;

    public DoSomethingWithAttachmentAction(MyAttachmentService myAttachmentService) {
        this.myAttachmentService = myAttachmentService;
    }

    public String doExecute() {
        myAttachmentService.someMethod();
    }
}
```

But then I'm getting the following error at runtime:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.atlassian.jira.bc.issue.attachment.AttachmentService] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [attachmentService, myAttachmentService]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:621)
    ...
```

How to fix it and use my new component?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use also `component-import` and say which interface to use - `MyAttachmentService` , this should configure spring ioc